# R function logic with map and dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe

I am new to R and am working on converting an R function to C#. While I have figured out many things from the R program, I am stuck at a particular logic and am totally unable to get past this correctly.

This is the piece of code,

```
result <- map(
  unique(dfcount$b_id),
  function(id){
     out <- dfloss[
         dfcount[b_id == id,][, b_id := NULL],
         .(execrate = sum(rate *(beta_func(i.loss / loss, mdr)),na.rm = TRUE)
         ),
         on = c("loss > loss"),
         by = .EACHI,
         nomatch = NULL,
         allow.cartesian = TRUE
]
       return(out)
      }) %>% rbindlist()
```

Here `dfcount` and `dfloss` and data.frames, which has all the columns used in the map function. While I understand the `map` function is trying to map each value with the output from the function, I do not understand the logic used to create the out variable. It would be helpful if I could get step by step explanation of each line from the out variable, especially the lines `dfcount[b_id == id,][, b_id := NULL] and .(execrate = sum(rate *(beta_func(i.loss / loss, mdr)), na.rm = TRUE)`

Here the `beta_func` is a separate function with a simple logic that returns a vector output.

Please help as I am new to R. I am totally clueless about the logic in the out function despite reading all the data.frames documentations.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Well, one cause of your confusion might be the fact that `dfcount` and `dfloss` are _not_ data frames. They are objects of class `data.table`, not `data.frame`. You need to read  `?data.table::\`[.data.table\``, not `?\`[.data.frame\``.

Comment: Yes right, that is a data.table. I would appreciate if you could explain whats happening in the out function, especially the dfcount[b_id == id,][, b_id := NULL] part. My understanding is that it is joining both tables on loss >= loss and creating a new column execrate with a specific logic. But i do not understand the b_id part as the data in the execrate is still a column list data. Kindly elaborate on that.